# Installing Go 16.6 on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: golang

I used the following code to download and install the latest Go version

```
wget -c https://dl.google.com/go/go1.16.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz -O - | sudo tar -xz -C /usr/local
```

Everything seemed to have gone alright, however, when I try to verify the installation using:

```
go version
```

I get the following error:

> -bash: /usr/local/go/bin/go: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

I have been searching for a solution but could not find anything helpful yet. I am trying to install Go on an s390x arch instead of standard amd64.

Comment: If you scroll down the [GO Downloads page](https://golang.google.cn/dl/), there is [go1.16.6.linux-s390x.tar.gz](https://golang.google.cn/dl/go1.16.6.linux-s390x.tar.gz) ...

Comment: @steeldriver thank you,  i missed it.

Comment: @steeldriver this resolved the issue, go is up and running now, thank you

Comment: BTW is there a typo in your title, or are you really trying to install [GoLand: A Clever IDE to Go by JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/) ?

Comment: @steeldriver it is edited now, I meant go Language, it is also known as golang in some circles.

Comment: Thanks - I thought that's what you meant, but didn't want to edit the title myself without checking!

Answer (score 3):

@steeldriver mentioned that go specific build for s390x is available on the go download page

> If you scroll down the GO Downloads page, there is
> go1.16.6.linux-s390x.tar.gz ...

I installed this version and the problem is resolved.